# Authentication with basic type api

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

After a good amount of time, I found the solution through an authentication plugin that is easy to install via composer with the command:

```
composer require "cakephp/authentication:^2.0"
```

After that, just generate the crud via terminal and check them to send json type data. It can be done as follows:

```
$this->response
    ->withType('application/json')
    ->withStatus(200)
    ->withStringBody(json_encode($dataOrMessage));
```

Add the function in entity to encrypt the password that the user registers:

```
protected function _setPassword(string $password) : ?string {
    if (strlen($password) > 0) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Implementing the AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface interface in the Application class and adding its requirements, in addition to the login and logout functions of the aforementioned plugin, you can [view here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html#adding-login)

The login function will look something like this:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

        if ($result && $result->isValid()) {
            return $this->response
                ->withType('application/json')
                ->withStatus(200)
                ->withStringBody(json_encode($result->getData()));
        } else {
            return $this->response
                ->withType('application/json')
                ->withStatus(401)
                ->withStringBody(json_encode(['message' => 'User or password incorrect!']));
        }
    }
}
```

There is not only this solution, but it was the one I found and that I found to be easier to implement.

Comment: Would you please check this example to hash your password and then try again ?
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html#adding-password-hashing

Comment: I tried again with the link sent, but still no success. I add the function to encrypt the password in the users entity.